# "yz_" option_name in wp_options table

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm doing cleaning for unused plugins and I find lots of names of **"yz_"** or **"_yz"** in wp_options table.

**

### [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wB2v.png)

**

I want to know if this part of the plugin is unused / uninstalled or important parts of wordpress that shouldn't be deleted?

I have Google it with the keywords "yz_", "**what is yz_ in wp_options**" and so on. However, I did not find anything relevant.

Comment: I don't know why someone gives -1 for this. If you feel this question is ridiculous because it's too easy, just answer it. Thans to @Howard E for your help. so I know that I can delete the "yz_" option name from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`yz` is not a default option in WordPress

It could be this -> https://youzer.kainelabs.com/

Comment: oh you're right, I used it a few months ago. thank you